# Are there any connections between USA's Mr. Robot and Channel 4's Utopia?

Tags: mr-robot, utopia

There appears to be some strong similarities between Mr. Robot and Utopia. The stories are very different, but stylistically, there seems to be a lot of similarities between the two from the pacing to the soundtrack to the overall 'vibe' from the characters.

However, I don't see an obvious connection between the two shows via the production crews.

*Is* there a connection between the two via certain key personnel, or is it that Mr. Robot is merely borrowing from it stylistically (intentionally or unintentionally)? If the latter, are any of the creators of the show documented mentioning Utopia as an inspiration?

Comment: Have you looked at the IMDb pages for the two? That would be the first stop if you want to compare personnel.

Comment: I know right! Total Utopia vibes. I think it's the BG score and shot compositions. It's on the same lines